# Can I simply update from 2.6.2779 -> 2.6.2958, shared hosting

Tags: updating

Do I need to go through and install all the previous updates before installing 2.6.2958 (current 2.6.2779) OR can I simply use the instructions on this page https://craftcms.com/docs/updating and install version 2.6.2958.

Any recommendations would be appreciated since I have never used Craft before and/or done any installations/updates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a backup of files and database first then click update (or upload a new /craft/app folder if you've got automatic updates turned off) - there are no breaking changes in Craft 2.6

Comment: Im assuming auto-updates are off since I only have a download button option, or maybe b/c I missed the critical update a few updates earlier.

Comment: In that case, you can download Craft, then just replace the /app folder on the server with the one from the zip file. To reduce downtime, you can upload the new app folder as "_app", then when it's finished uploading, rename the current app folder to "_old_app", and rename the new app folder to app. Then delete the old app folder.